# Not connecting to Internet using Cisco Meraki Z1

Tags: cisco, router

I was trying to use a Cisco Meraki Z1 router, but because of some reasons, I cannot connect it to the Internet in my office.

I when inserted the RJ cable to the Internet port, the LEDS were glowing. 
Also, I could test the Internet speed from `setup.meraki.com`. But then when I try to access Internet through Wi-Fi, it says no Internet.

I have used the same thing at home, where I directly connected it to the modem, and there it worked perfectly.

Can anyone help me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to edit you question to include more information. For example, how are you doing DHCP? It would help if you explained more about your office network, too. I assume you control the office network.

Comment: What Ron said.^^ I assume WiFi is enabled on your Z1? And, your issue may have nothing to do with the Z1. Is your PC connecting to the SSID being broadcast by the Z1? If so, what IP are you getting? Does it match that of the scope be handed out by your Z1? Can you ping 8.8.8.8? If you can you have a DNS issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Meraki Z1 local status page at my.meraki.com or wired.meraki.com will:

1. Verify connectivity from your wireless client to the gateway
2. Provide information on the health of the Internet connection